# How do I set a default value in an input field with CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

I thought I could just use "value" like below, but it doesn't seem to work.  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<?php 
                echo $this->Form->create('Email', array('url'=>'/emails/add', 'value'=>'enter your email address', 'inputDefaults'=>array('label'=>false))); 
                echo $this->Form->input('Email.email');
                echo $this->Form->end('SIGN-UP');
            ?>
```

---

I tried setting in my controller (ty @Jared), but it doesn't seem to work.  Thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?php
class EmailsController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Emails';

    function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter(); 
        $this->Auth->allowedActions = array('add');
    }


function create() {
    $this->data['Email']['email'] = 'enter your email address';
}
}
```

Comment: If you mean you want to set an initial value to your form input when loading @blivet solution is the one in line with CakePHP standards

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're setting the value in the wrong place. You want to set the default value of the input element like this:

```
echo $form->input('email',array('default'=>'enter your email address'));
```

Look at [this page in the manual](http://book.cakephp.org/view/755/options-default).

Comment: I'm a noob - TYVM!  I should have RTFM. ;)  Honestly, I thought I tried that, but couldn't get it to work - I should have known it'd been that easy, and was hoping it would be!  /ugh at me

Comment: Just a small note, if you want to set a default value for a checkbox add as checked add "checked"=>"checked" to the options array.

Answer (score 0):

Use a controller to set defaults. It prevents any issues that might happen and you get your default value returned, not the intended user input value:

```
class ProjectsController extends AppController
{
  function create()
  {
    $this->data['Project']['name'] = 'Default Project Name';
  }
}
```

As seen on: [Snook.ca](http://snook.ca/archives/cakephp/cakephp_setting)

Comment: I appreciate the answer, @Jared - I'm sure it's right, but I cannot get it to work correctly - thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?  (added some code to question)

Comment: I wish I could be of more help, but my cake PHP is limited. I had helped implement this for another project... I am a Ruby on Rails guy myself.